# First JS script tag works normally, second script tag does not read the file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to use multiple JS files for my page, but for some reason, whenever I attempt to add a second , the second one does not work, not matter where I position it, and changing ID tags doesn't help either

Here's the HTML code

```
<div id="buttoncontainer" class="buttoncontainer">

<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>

<div class="rightmenu">
        <div id="test" style="height:400px;width:100px;outline:solid red 1px;">
    </div>
```

And here's the JS files

menu.js

```
let headerContent = `
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/homebutton.gif" class="button"></a>

  <a href="blog/blogmain.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/blogbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

  <a href="art/artmain.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/artbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

<div class="dropmenu1">
  <a href="art/fanartmain.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/fanartbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

    <div class="dropmenu1-content">
    <a href="links/links.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/linksbutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="dropmenu2">
  <a href="art/donate.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/donatebutton.gif" class="button"></a>

    <div class="dropmenu2-content">
    <a href="comissions/comissions.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/comissionsbutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>
    </div>
    </div>

  <a href="guestbook/guestbook.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/guestbookbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

<div class="dropmenu3">
  <a href="art/about.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/aboutbutton.gif" class="button"></a>
    
    <div class="dropmenu3-content">
    <a href="https://junessai.github.io/Old-JuneSSai.net-Archive/" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/buttons/oldsitebutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>

    <a href="changelog/changelog.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/changelogbutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
`;
document.querySelector('#buttoncontainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerContent);
```

test.js

```
let headerContent = `
 <img src="images/test.png">
`;
document.querySelector('#test').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerContent);
```

Comment: Well the script tags access the elements before they exist on the page. Errors in your console should give you indication about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: How do you check errors in console?
I always do my works on vim

Comment: You need to learn about the development tools in the browser. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/

Comment: Alright, I got the console debug thing now, the only error message I'm getting is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'headerContent' has already been declared", but I'm not sure what to do with that

Comment: You have already declared `headerContent` in `menu.js`. Try changing the variable name in `test.js`

Comment: Rapid solution: rename headerContent in test.js to headerContent1.
You already declared headerContent in menu.js

Comment: I changed the name to headerContent1 on the test.js file but now all I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
    at test.js:5", here is how the code looks "let headerContent1 = `
 <img src="images/test.png">
`;
document.querySelector('#test').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerContent1);"

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple JavaScript files, they all share the same global namespace.
Because your global variable `headerContent` has already been declared in `menu.js`, `test.js` cannot share the same global variable name.

You could rename `headerContent` in one of the files to a different name, such as `menuHeaderContent` and `testHeaderContent`, to differentiate the two variables.

Or you could put everything inside of `{}` so any global variables you create are not within the actual global scope:

```
{
let headerContent = `
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/homebutton.gif" class="button"></a>

  <a href="blog/blogmain.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/blogbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

  <a href="art/artmain.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/artbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

<div class="dropmenu1">
  <a href="art/fanartmain.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/fanartbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

    <div class="dropmenu1-content">
    <a href="links/links.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/linksbutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="dropmenu2">
  <a href="art/donate.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/donatebutton.gif" class="button"></a>

    <div class="dropmenu2-content">
    <a href="comissions/comissions.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/comissionsbutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>
    </div>
    </div>

  <a href="guestbook/guestbook.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/guestbookbutton.gif" class="button"></a>

<div class="dropmenu3">
  <a href="art/about.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/aboutbutton.gif" class="button"></a>
    
    <div class="dropmenu3-content">
    <a href="https://junessai.github.io/Old-JuneSSai.net-Archive/" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/buttons/oldsitebutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>

    <a href="changelog/changelog.html">
    <img src="images/buttons/changelogbutton.gif" class="button dropbutton"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
`;
document.querySelector('#buttoncontainer').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerContent);
}
```